# How to pass an Array from x-slot to layouts in Laravel blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

How to pass an Array from x-slot to layouts in Laravel blade template.
This is my layout file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<!--wrapper-->
<div class="wrapper">

    {{ do something to the Array $arr  }}

    {{ $slot }}

</div>
<!--end wrapper-->
</body>
</html>
```

below is my view file

```
<x-layout>
    {{ $arr }} <!-- how to pass it to the layout file -->
    <x-slot:arr> array here </x-slot:arr>

</x-layout>
```

My question is how to pass the $arr to the layout file

My question is how to pass the $arr to the layout file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with:

```
@slot('arr')
    {{ $arr }}
@endslot
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer(
        'layout.app', 
        function ($view) {
            $view->with('mayArray', $data);
        }
    );
}
```